# What's the difference between calling daemon() and calling fork(), setsid(), fork(), etc.?

Tags: c, unix, fork, daemon

I've been looking at creating Unix dæmons, and there seem to be two methods. The long-winded one, which seems to come up when searching is to call `fork()`, `setsid()`, `fork()` again, `chdir()` to somewhere safe, set `umask()` and, finally, `close()` `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

Running `man daemon`, however, brings up information on a `daemon()` function, which seems to do all the same stuff as above. Are there any differences between the two approaches or is `daemon()` just a convenience function that does the same thing as the long-winded method? Is either one better, especially for a novice C programmer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `daemon` function is not defined in POSIX, so its implementation (if any) could behave differently on different platforms.

On Linux with glibc, `daemon` only does one fork, optionally `chdir`s (but only to `/`, you can't specify a path), does not touch `umask`, and does not close the `std*` descriptors (it optionally reopens them to `/dev/null` though). ([source](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/misc/daemon.c))

So it depends on the platform, and at least one implementation does less than what you do. If you need all of what you're doing, stick with that (or stick to a platform where the `daemon` function does exactly that).

Comment: Leaving file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 open to `/dev/null` is preferable to closing them, because otherwise the next files your daemon opens (log files, sockets, ...) will get those file descriptors - which might bite you, say when some library you're calling decides to write an error to `stderr`...

Comment: Good call on not closing descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `daemon` is not conforming to any standard. Better use standard conforming functions (like POSIX-defined `fork` and `setsid`).

Answer (score 1):

The daemon call summarizes the long-winded fork procedure, and I don't recall any implementation that does anything more.

Since daemon() is a high-level concept, it's definitely to be preferred for novice and experienced programmers.